# Eclipse doesn't start on Debian

Tags: eclipse, debian

I have a problem with `Eclipse IDE` on `Debian`. When I try to launch it by typing `"eclipse"` in the terminal, nothing happens, and I don't have any error message.

I tried to remove and reinstall eclipse-plateform but it still doesn't work.

I don't know why it does that, it worked perfectly some times ago.

Comment: Can you please clearify what "nothing happens" exactly means? Does the command return immediately or does it hang? Is there probably any error message?

Comment: The command hangs for 2 seconds and then returns. There is no error message.

Comment: Try using the openjdk jre as suggested below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably that's a problem with the jre you are using.

I remember having similar problems running eclipse with the gcj-jre. Using openjdk solved the issue for me.

Try using :

```
update-alternatives --config java
```

and choose openjdk instead of gij to see if the problem still remains.